# Can I Use SignalR for Approval Process System

Tags: signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

I want to design an approval process in my application using .Net Core WebAPI.
The scenario is when a leave application is requested I need to send notification to different levels of approvers already configured in the system.
Can I use SignalR for this type of scenario? This is a web application. Client side is using React.js and server side is .NET core API. I am new to SignalR.

Comment: Yes you can, But SignalR can jsut send notification, If you need to do some other operations like adding leave records to the database, you may also need to add other code.